# One Note 2016 Export

Tags: microsoft-onenote, screenshot, microsoft-office-2016, greenshot

I can export screenshots into Excel, Outlook, Word and PowerPoint, but not into OneNote.  I have Microsoft Office 2016.

What do I need to do to make the export into One Note work?

I want to export from Greenshot and import into OneNote

Comment: Export Into? Do you mean Import images into? Please explain the use case and replication steps.

Comment: sorry, I am referring to the usage of Greenshot export into Microsoft One Note 2016...

Comment: Import into Microsoft One Note 2016 / export Greenshot

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: this should be a comment, but not enough reputation :-/*

So, is there a OneNote option available at all? If yes, what happens when you try to use it? Do you get an error message? If yes, what does it say?

[Two](https://greenshot.atlassian.net/browse/BUG-1899) [people](https://greenshot.atlassian.net/browse/FEATURE-626) have reported issues with Greenshot and OneNote, obviously it does not work with some installations. The latter also suggests [a workaround that requires to remove a specific registry key](https://greenshot.atlassian.net/browse/FEATURE-626?focusedCommentId=86023&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-86023).